# Opening page in facebook app only opens app itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-mobile

I have jQuery Mobile app, wherein I have a link to an associated facebook page.  What I want to do is open the page in the facebook app if it's installed, otherwise open in the default browser.  I have code that opens the facebook app, but no more than that - the desired page is not loaded.  Here's the code that I'm using to open the app (derived from [How to launch apps (facebook/twitter/etc) from mobile browser but fall back to hyperlink if the app isn't installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/how-to-launch-apps-facebook-twitter-etc-from-mobile-browser-but-fall-back-to-h) )

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function (e, data) {
  $('a.openapp').on('click', function (event) {
    uriSchemeWithHyperlinkFallback($(this).data('scheme'), $(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  function uriSchemeWithHyperlinkFallback(uri, href) {
    if(!window.open(uri)){
      window.location = href;
    }
  }
});
```

And, here's variations on the links that I've tried:

```
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" data-scheme="fb://page/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" data-scheme="fb://page/233457512435/" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" data-scheme="fb://facewebmodal/f?href=https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" data-scheme="fb://profile/233457512435/" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
```

I've done a *lot* of searching (see links below).  I gather that I need a special page ID that can be found through graph.facebook.com, but that appears to be no longer available.  It also appears that facebook is changing so quickly that any posts over 6 months old are out of date.  I did view the page's source code and found a uid value (as per one of the links), but alas, no joy.  I welcome any insights here, as I'm stuck!

Related links:

[HTML link to launch an app if installed or go to a website if not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153863/html-link-to-launch-an-app-if-installed-or-go-to-a-website-if-not)

[How to launch apps (facebook/twitter/etc) from mobile browser but fall back to hyperlink if the app isn't installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675535/how-to-launch-apps-facebook-twitter-etc-from-mobile-browser-but-fall-back-to-h)

[Open Facebook Page in Facebook App (if installed) on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564211/open-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-if-installed-on-android)

[Open Facebook page in Native Facebook IOS App via simple URL Sheme issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107627/open-facebook-page-in-native-facebook-ios-app-via-simple-url-sheme-issue)

[How to open facebook page in facebook app in iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984468/how-to-open-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-in-iphone)

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-this-hack-to-open-a-specific-facebook-page-from-your-android-app/

Update:

After further investigation and much trial and error, I finally got this working.  Here's the significant link:  [Open link to Facebook page from iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589367/open-link-to-facebook-page-from-ios-app)

To summarize, open the desired facebook page in a browser, view the source (Ctrl+U in most browsers), then search for al:ios:url.  You should be able to find the line:

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="fb://page/?id='your_page_numeric_id'">
```

There's the URL you need.  So, in my code (see above), this link now works as desired:

```
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/Raven-Rock-Ramble-233457512435/" data-scheme="fb://page/?id=233457512435" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
```

The main takeaway here is that the URL syntax for the facebook app is **fb://page/?id=**

**Update September 15, 2017:**

I'm re-visiting this code.  It seems to work well enough on IOS, but not on Android, where it just opens the facebook app but does not load the page :-(

**Update September 19, 2017:**

OK, I got it working on both iOS and Android now.  The two have a slightly different syntax.  Here's the current, working js code:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#home", function (e, data) {
  $('a.openapp').on('click', function (event) {
    var scheme;
    if (iPhone)
      scheme = "fb://page/?id=" + $(this).data('id');
    else
      scheme = "fb://page/" + $(this).data('id');
    uriSchemeWithHyperlinkFallback(scheme, $(this).attr('href'));
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  // Open page in app, else open page in browser 
  function uriSchemeWithHyperlinkFallback(uri, href) {
    if (!window.open(uri)) {
      window.location = href;
    }
  }  
});
```

and here's the associated html:

```
<a class="openapp" href="https://www.facebook.com/CFFCarolinasRaleigh/" data-id="134656996545475" ><img class="social_logo" src="./img/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a>
```

Notice that iOS seems to require ?id= and Android does not.  "iPhone" is a global variable I set elsewhere,

```
var useragent = navigator.userAgent; // cache the userAgent info
var iPhone = (useragent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g));
```

**Update July 15, 2020:**

The page source technique described above no longer seems to work.  However, there are web sites that will return the numeric page id.  See
https://fb-search.com/find-my-facebook-id.

For the particular page I was referencing, the urls were somewhat different on iOS and android:

iOS: `fb://profile/?id=<numeric page id>`
android: `fb:///page/<numeric page id>`

That makes no sense to me, but it worked.